# webkit rendering issue on Android 2.3 - some listview elements have blurry borders

Tags: android, css, kendo-ui

I'm not sure if this is a webkit rendering bug in gingerbread, or an issue with a framework I'm using to build my website (Kendo UI Mobile)...

I have multiple list items in a listview. There is a 2px border that separates each item from eachother.

What's strange is that every even number border is blurry, while every odd number border is clear. As I scroll the page, the issue will switch back and forth between the borders (even borders clear, odd borders blurry. scroll. even borders blurry, odd borders clear).

Does anyone know if this is a rendering issue is in the actual webkit core that android's 2.3+ default browser uses, or could it be the css being applied through Kendo UI Mobile?

I do notice on kendo list items, a `-webkit-translatez(0)` rule is being applied.. but I have no idea if this is relevant.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I can live with it, but it's just annoying and all android versions < 2.3 render the borders properly.

I am using the latest JQuery and Kendo UI Mobile major releases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This its a change in the latest version to avoid missing borders that happened sometimes in the previous versions due to Android bug. Now the borders are done with box shadows but in Android 2.3, box-shadows without blur are not rendered at all (another Android bug), thus we are doing them with blur, hence what you see.

Comment: Very interesting, and makes perfect sense, especially working around the many pitfalls of android 2.3. Thanks a lot for the update!